# Checking and Unchecking checkboxes according to the data from SQL database is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have 40 checkboxes , and when a user register his account, for each user 40 rows of data is generated in a sql table like

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
| Id | UserName |   Category   |    CheckBoxValue    | Checked |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1  | Sabab    | Emotion      | Maintaining Emotion | no      |
| 2  | Sabab    | Emotion      | Expressing Emotion  | no      |
| 3  | Sabab    | Self Defence | Swimming            | no      |
| .  | xx       | xx           | xx                  | no      |
| 40 | Sabab    | Personality  | Punctuality         | no      |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
```

and when another user register another 40 rows are generated having the same values of  Category, Checkbox value, Checked value.
Only the ID and UserName Differs.

When a user log into his account he can check some checkboxes and update the database . Suppose ,Sabab after logging int his account , checks  Maintaining Emotion 
and Expressing emotion. and then hit the update button, then the checked  value of ID no 1 and 2 will be yes.

and if sabab logs out from his account and later again log into his account then , he should see that Maintaining Emotion and Expressing emotion checkboxes are checked.

To update the database I have used the following code:

```
  protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserManager managerObject=new UserManager();


            if (Session["userType"]==null)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You have to log in first.');</script>");
            }

            else if (Session["userType"]!=null)
            {
                if (Session["userType"].ToString() == "trainee")
                {
                    if (perceivingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked)
                    {
                       managerObject.UpdateCheckboxValueOfIndexPage(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Maintaining Emotion","yes");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        managerObject.UpdateCheckboxValueOfIndexPage(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Maintaining Emotion", "no");   

                    }


                    if (usingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked)
                    {
                        managerObject.UpdateCheckboxValueOfIndexPage(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Expressing Emotion", "yes");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        managerObject.UpdateCheckboxValueOfIndexPage(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Using Emotion", "no");

                    }




                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Your choices have been updated');</script>");


 }



 }
```

to load the checkboxes have used the following method ,LoadCheckboxes() and have put it into the page load method:

```
 public void LoadCheckBoxes()
        {
             UserManager managerObject=new UserManager();

             if (managerObject.CheckBoxChecked(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Maintaining Emotion")=="yes")
             {
                 maintainingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked = true;
             }

             else
             {
                 maintainingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked = false;
             }




             if (managerObject.CheckBoxChecked(Session["userName"].ToString(), "Expressing Emotions")=="yes")
             {
                 expressingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked = true;

             }

             else
             {
                 expressingEmotionsCheckbox.Checked = false;
             }

        }



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["userType"] == "trainee")
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    LoadCheckBoxes();
                }



            }


        }
```

When the user Sabab enters his account , then everything is fine, and , the checkboxes loads according to the checked and unchecked value from database. 
    But if Sabab unchecks a checked checkbox, and then  try to reload the page, then the page is not reloaded . it seems that the page is strucked.

Comment: You have two of the main methods missing. Can you post the code you have for `managerObject.CheckBoxChecked(....)` and `LoadCheckBoxes();`

Comment: For Manager : https://pastebin.com/DCWwhgPz @Seany84

Comment: For Gateway : https://pastebin.com/VHCHcvuh  @Seany84